# Can I access errors for google apps email routing

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, email-forwarding

I have a domain which is set-up through google apps for your domain (GAYD)

There are a couple of accounts on it.  The domain has been set to deliver the rest to a third account "catchall@domain". That account has then been set to forward to my gmail account.

Some times mails sent to pick-an-email@domain get delivered. Other times they don't. They are not getting through to catchall@domain either.

The correct route should be

1. send mail -> us_amazon@domain
2. 'us_amazon' not recognised so send to catchall
3. catchall account forwards to gmail
4. read the email and smile contentedly

For the sending email accounts that do not get through I have tried delivery and read receipts.  The delivery receipt says <paraphrased> delivered to google, no further receipts will be generated.

Changing the catchall account to forward (instead of forward and archive) makes no difference.

Interestingly, adding us_amazon as a nickname for the catchall account does seem to work.

**Note** that in this case the issue was that the email was ending up in the spam folder, but the Spam was not being shown as default.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem. Are pick-an-email@domain addresses going to catchall@domain or does `pick-an-email` stand for one of the "real" addresses?

Comment: Is the catchall address an account or just an address?

Comment: Hopefully addressed comments in question rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must isolate the problem. Try disabling forwarding completely and send an email to an address that doesn't work. Does the email get delivered to the catch all? Check the spam folder as well.

**If the email was delivered**: then it's a problem with the forwarding. Make sure that you are not forwarding to an address that the email originated from or was already part of the forwarding. Gmail is smart enough to not forward these messages as they will cause an infinite loop.

**If the email wasn't delivered**: please post an example of an email address that isn't being caught by the catch all address. Maybe you are using illegal characters or something. For example, make sure the plus is not used, as this will cause the email to go to the base address without the plus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The initial issue is "spam". The secondary issue was that the mail for GAYD does not show the spam folder by default.

Haven't accepted answer, because a) I'm not all the way there yet (too much is spam) and b) it's not really "accessing errors" as per the question. [ rewrite of question will probably do it ]